# Clion multiple debug configurations in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have project with qt-gui and command line only version. 
I have release and debug configuration for both gui and non gui version. I want to have different names for debug configuration in gui and non gui version. But when configuration has different name than Debug, debugging does not work and it behaves like release build.
Is there any possibility to have multiple debug configurations, each with different name?
[image: my generation settings]

Answer (score 0):

Note, if you click on "Debug" configuration, the following hint is shown up underneath the "CMake options":

> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug will be passed automatically

So, you shouldn try to add `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` into "CMake options" expliticly when you create your own configuration with a different name, which is inherently a Debug configuration

Comment: But in this situation, it says: 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DebugNoGui will be passed automatically.
So even if i copied adn renamed the debug configuration, the 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
is not passed, and it always has same value as name of the configuration. So it looks to me like I need to add this option explicitly.